# Magento 2 Add product to category (code)

Tags: categories, magento2

I want to create products by their code, and I want to add products to categories.
How to add products to categories by code?
I tried to add category to product `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product`, but there no method setCategory or something like that.
Then I tried to add products to category `Magento\Catalog\Model\Category`, and there no method addProduct or something like that. 
  I saw function

```
CategoryLinkManagementInterface -> assignProductToCategories(
$product->getSku(),
$product->getCategoryIds() //but there is not categories yet
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkManagementInterface
     */
    protected $_categoryLinkManagement;

$this->_categoryLinkManagement->assignProductToCategories($sku, $categoryIds);
//where $sku is sku of product, and $categoryIds is array of real categories ids
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get category Ids and product Id to set data: impliment this :

```
$this->getCategoryLinkManagement()->assignProductToCategories(
                $product->getSku(),
                $product->getCategoryIds()
            );

also impliment this function :

private function getCategoryLinkManagement()
{
    if (null === $this->categoryLinkManagement) {
        $this->categoryLinkManagement = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get('Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkManagementInterface');
    }
    return $this->categoryLinkManagement;
}
```

rest dependency you should manage for :

`Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkManagementInterface`

```
intialize : protected $categoryLinkManagement;
```

Comment: I am getting below error,Could not save product with position 0 to category 8

Answer (score 0):

```
    $objectManager = ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $catalogProduct = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
    $catalogProduct->setSku('sku-1');
    $catalogProduct->setName('name');
    $catalogProduct->setAttributeSetId(4);
    $catalogProduct->setStatus(1); // Status on product enabled/ disabled 1/0
    $catalogProduct->setVisibility(4);
    $catalogProduct->setTypeId('simple'); // type of product (simple/virtual/downloadable/configurable)
    $catalogProduct->setPrice(100);

    $catalogProduct->setCategoryIds(['id']); // here you are

    $catalogProduct->setStockData([
        'is_in_stock' => true,
        'qty'         => 10
    ]);

    $catalogProduct->setStoreId(1); // $this->storeManagerInterface->getStore()->getId()
    $catalogProduct->setWebsiteIds([1]); // $this->storeManagerInterface->getStore()->getWebsiteId()

    $catalogProduct->save();
```